# CLLocationManager responsiveness

Tags: ios, performance, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have an app that revolves around the device's GPS and the information that comes from it. It is important that the location data be accurate and up-to-date. I know that the device is limited by its GPS and the GPS's limits, but I was wondering if there is anything I can do to tweak/improve the performance of the iPhone GPS, particularly in the speed area. Because location updates lag about 3-5 seconds behind the real-time location of the device, the velocity reported by the location manager also lags that far behind the real-time value. In my case, that is simply too long. I understand that there might not be anything I can do, but has anyone had any success in improving the responsiveness of the iPhone GPS? Every little bit makes a difference.

Edit 1:

My location manager is inside a singleton class, as Apple recommends.

Inside SingletonDataController.m:

```
static CLLocationManager* locationManager;
locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.headingFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone;

if(([[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] == UIDeviceBatteryStateFull)) {
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
} else {
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}

[sharedSingleton setLocationManager:locationManager];
[locationManager release];
```

Inside MapView.m (where the location manager is actually used):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil {
    //setup
    [SingletonDataController sharedSingleton].locationManager.delegate = self;
    //more setup
}

- (void)batteryChanged {
    if(([[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] == UIDeviceBatteryStateFull)) {
        [SingletonDataController sharedSingleton].locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    } else {
        [SingletonDataController sharedSingleton].locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //setup
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
      addObserver:self 
         selector:@selector(batteryChanged) 
             name:UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification 
           object:nil];
    //other setup
}
```

The data handling happens inside `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`. I don't believe that inefficiency here is the cause of the lag.

`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` calls this method to update the UI:

```
- (void)setLabels:(CLLocation*)newLocation fromOldLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation {
    //set speed label
    if(iterations > 0) {
        if(currentSpeed > keyStopSpeedFilter) {
            if(isFollowing) {
                [mapViewGlobal setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake([newLocation coordinate], mapViewGlobal.region.span)];
            }

            NSString* currentSpeedString;
            if(isCustomary) {
                currentSpeedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.1f miles per hour", (currentSpeed * 2.23693629f)];
            } else {
                currentSpeedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.1f km per hour", (currentSpeed * 3.6f)];
            }

            [speedLabel setText:currentSpeedString];
            [currentSpeedString release];
        } else {
            speedLabel.text = @"Not moving";
        }
    }

    //set average speed label
    if(iterations > 4 && movementIterations > 2) {
        NSString* averageSpeedString;
        if(isCustomary) {
            averageSpeedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.1f miles per hour", (float)((speedAverages / (long double)movementIterations) * 2.23693629f)];
        } else {
            averageSpeedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.1f km per hour", (float)((speedAverages / (long double)movementIterations) * 3.6f)];
        }
        [averageSpeedLabel setText:averageSpeedString];
        [averageSpeedString release];
    }

    //set elapsed time label
    NSInteger seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dataObject.locationManagerStartDate];
    NSInteger minutes = seconds / 60;
    NSInteger hours = minutes / 60;

    //get remainder
    seconds %= 60;

    NSString* timeString;
    NSString* secondsString;
    NSString* minutesString;
    NSString* hoursString;

    if((seconds % 60) < 10) {
        secondsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0%i", seconds];
    } else {
        secondsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", seconds];
    }

    if((minutes % 60) < 10) {
        minutesString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0%i", minutes];
    } else {
        minutesString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", minutes];
    }

    if((hours % 60) < 10) {
        hoursString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0%i", hours];
    } else {
        hoursString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", hours];
    }

    timeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@:%@:%@", hoursString, minutesString, secondsString];

    [elapsedTimeLabel setText:timeString];

    [timeString release], timeString = nil;
    [secondsString release], secondsString = nil;
    [minutesString release], minutesString = nil;
    [hoursString release], hoursString = nil;

    NSString* totalDistanceString;
    if(isCustomary) {
        totalDistanceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Total: %.2f mi", (float)distance * 0.000621371192f];
    } else {
        totalDistanceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Total: %.2f km", (float)distance / 1000.0f];
    }
    [customTopBar setTitle:totalDistanceString];
    [totalDistanceString release];
}
```

With a couple of NSDates and NSLogs I have found that the execution of the entire `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` (not just the label updating method) never takes more than about 8ms on my iPhone 4; in other words, the data handling isn't the problem.

Comment: Show us how you are getting the location data. That lag is not normal.

Comment: Added code. I can post more if needed.

Comment: 3-5 seconds might be a bit of a exaggeration; it's late and the range 3-5 just popped into my head for some reason. Tomorrow I will run some tests to get exact numbers.

Comment: Nothing strange there. What are you doing in locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:, and how are you determining that it is lagging?

Comment: OK, now I am confused. What is lagging? The location you get in the didUpdate or the location that is showing on the map?

Comment: The data received from the location manager is what is lagging. For example, if I am driving down the road at thirty miles an hour and drive over a bridge, the location manager doesn't show my location over the bridge for a couple seconds. If I am walking at four miles an hour and speed up to seven, the data from the location manager doesn't reflect that change for a couple of seconds. That's what I mean.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with the latency issue.  But I think you can simplify the initialization of secondsString/minutesString/hoursString buy using a @"%02i" to automatically format the number with a leading 0 without explicitly testing for "<10"

Comment: Thanks for that tip, it really cleaned up my code!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

OK, a couple of things could improve your lag. First of all, use kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation always. There is no real battery usage difference between that and kCLLocationAccuracyBest, they both use the GPS at top speed. The main difference is in the post-processing that Apple does.

Second, there is no need to filter for speed == 0. Apple already does that filtering: if your speed from the GPS drops below a certain threshold (about 4 km/h), the OS assumes you are standing still, and it substitutes the same location value for all subsequent samples. It does that until it thinks you are moving again. I assume they do that to avoid "jittering" on the map when you are standing still. In fact, speed drops to 0 already for the last real value of a sequence of "standing-still" values, so if you filter on speed == 0 than you are missing one real GPS sample.

Unfortunately, they is no way to avoid that filtering and get real GPS samples. I talked to Apple about it, and their response was that they are not going to change the behaviour. kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation does less aggressive filtering than kCLLocationAccuracyBest, so it's best to use that.

Third, you probably are already doing this, but make sure that you call "setNeedsDisplay" on your view right from the "didUpdateFromLocation:", to make sure that the map is actually redrawn.

If you do all that, you should have a lag of about 1 second. If you want to improve on the 1 second than you can try to use predictive techniques. From the last two locations, and the given speed, you can calculate where the next location is likely to be, and already display that location. I have had mixed results with that. It works well for fast movement that does not change speed suddenly, like driving a car. It works less well for slower movement like walking or biking.

Comment: Thanks so much ```kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation``` really helped me out. The location delegate methods run so much quicker now :)

Comment: @fishinear does ActivityType come into play wiht accuracy at all?

Answer (score 7):

In iPhone we can configure location services by two methods -

1. By using `Standard Location Services`, that is satellite GPS which provide you more accurate data.
2. By using `Significant Location Changes` that uses A-GPS or get location through wi-fi which provide less accurate data.

We can configure location services by any of these two methods but it depends on what is the requirement of the app. 
If the app is a `navigation app` or a `location tracking app` then we should use `Standard Location Services` but before using standard services we have in mind that if you want more accurate data then you have to suffer with `battery consume more quickly`. 
If the app don't require location update more frequently and also the `accuracy doesn't matter` a lot then we should `Significant Location Changes` because it will `save a lot of battery` consume as compare to Standard Location Service.

Standard Location Service uses `desiredAccuracy` and `distanceFilter` value to determine whether and when to deliver event.

`desiredAccuracy` is the parameter where you can define how much accuracy you want from GPS hardware. It uses some pre-defined constants as -

```
kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
kCLLocationAccuracyBest
kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
```

`distanceFilter` is the parameter where you have to define distance, means for how much distance gap you want to ask GPS hardware to send a location update.

In your case you are dealing with the speed parameter, so i guess its something related to navigation. So you should use `Standard Location Services`. I think you are also doing that but the  issue that you are facing is lag between location updates. Here i suggest you to modify your `desiredAccuracy` and `distanceFilter` value to this -

[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:10.0f];

by setting values to this you will get location update in less then 1 sec if your are driving.

One more thing you have to put in your mind that when you get location update you should check its `timestamp` value to ignore old location updates. Its because when you start `locationManager` by calling `startUpdatingLocation` then the first location you get may be your old location. Also you have to check for `horizontalAccuracy` value because first few location updates that you get are always not accurate and might have accuracy in 1000 or more that you are not looking for. So you have to check its value to ignore inaccurate location updates.

```
Note: If you try with different accuracy and different distance filter value then you will be more clear about it how accurate data iPhone GPS hardware return.
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the other good examples of how to use Core Location, also keep in mind the general technique for getting good kinematics results from a not-so-great sensor (e.g. smartphone location services) of [Kalman Filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).

It's a lot of math and testing and tweaking, but it does allow you to get what users would consider better results than simple data from the sensor provides.

This is what's used in avionics and things like radar processing systems.