# What google map and Apple map did to show MORE accurate location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, apple-maps

In my app, I am using CLLocationManager to get user's current location.

The problem is, most of the time, user would be indoor, or not very far from the building entrance when they launch my app for the very first time. As a result the location I get is not very accurate(more than 1km off).

Yet, at the same time, if I open either Google Map or Apple Map, they are able to display location with little discrepency(a few hundred meters). How they manage to do that ?

Comment: have you tried setting the desiredAccuracy as kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation ?

Comment: I hope this thread helps... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746675/cllocationmanager-responsiveness