# Getting wrong coordinates when tracked via Cellular in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am getting wrong coordinates using cellular data, but when I am using wifi it's getting currect coordinates. I am fetching coordinates using CLLocationManager. I have struck from one month. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
 self.locationManagerForCheckIn=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 self.locationManagerForCheckIn.delegate = self;
 self.locationManagerForCheckIn.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
 self.locationManagerForCheckIn.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
      if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
       [self.locationManagerForCheckIn requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

[self.locationManagerForCheckIn startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: hi please check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9954020/2910061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a common issue with cllocation  the actual accuracy is not guaranteed. as documentation

> When requesting high-accuracy location data, the initial event
>   delivered by the location service may not have the accuracy you
>   requested. The location service delivers the initial event as quickly
>   as possible. It then continues to determine the location with the
>   accuracy you requested and delivers additional events, as necessary,
>   when that data is available.

my suggesions for best results

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
```

and please check this also [locationmanager responsiveness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746675/cllocationmanager-responsiveness)